# Botão na MainActivity reseta Spinner em um DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, dialog, spinners

Possuo dois botões na MainActivity, no primeiro abre um custom DialogFragment com alguns spinners e no outro botão ele reseta os spinner desse DialogFragment.

Quando eu clico no botão de resetar ele chama este método que está no DialogFragment:

```
   public class FilterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    private View view;
    // ...

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NotNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_filters, container, false);

        // start the spinners and adapters here

        return view;
    }

    public void resetFilters() {
        if (view != null) {
            categorySpinner.setSelection(0);
            productSpinner.setSelection(0);
            priceSpinner.setSelection(0);
        }
    }
    // some more codes here
}
```

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private FilterDialogFragment filterDialog;
    private Button button_clear;
    private Button button_filter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button_clear = findViewById(R.id.button_clear);
        button_filter = findViewById(R.id.button_filter);

        filterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();

        button_filter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Show the dialog containing filter options
                filterDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FilterDialogFragment.TAG);
            }
        });

        button_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //reset all filters
                filterDialog.resetFilters();
            }
        });

        //some more codes here
    }
    //some more methods here
}
```

Mas ao clicar no botão que abre o DialogFragment, os valores dos Spinners se mantém os mesmos ao invés de retornar os dados da posição 0 de cada spinner.

Alguém saberia como resolver isso? já tentei de tudo e não consigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma maneira simples que acabei encontrando foi remover o método resetFilters no FilterDialogFragment e no botão da MainActivity instanciar um novo DialogFragment.

```
 button_clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //reset all filters
                filterDialog = new FilterDialogFragment();          
      }
        });
```